# subfigures: caption for every row and every column

Tags: floats, subcaption

I have three models that I test under different parameter configurations. I created a figure where every column corresponds to a model. I would like to add the value of the parameter at the left of every row. After reading [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212024/caption-on-the-left-of-lines-of-subfigures), this is what I do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$R=1$}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$R=2$}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$R=3$}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \caption{model A}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]  
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \caption{model B}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]  
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \caption{model C}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Grid test}
\end{figure}
```

But I get this:
[image: test]

How can I make it right?

Comment: I just updated my answer with another option that might be of interest for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility (the `%` signs suppressing spurious blank spaces are essential):

### Update

A modified version (the whole construct now stays inside the text width):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}% just for visiual guide

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{\dimexpr0.30\textwidth+20pt\relax}
    \makebox[20pt]{\raisebox{40pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$R=1$}}}%
    \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-20pt\relax]
    {test.png}
    \makebox[20pt]{\raisebox{40pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$R=2$}}}%
    \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-20pt\relax]
    {test.png}
    \makebox[20pt]{\raisebox{40pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$R=3$}}}%
    \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-20pt\relax]
    {test.png}
    \caption{model A}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]  
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \caption{model B}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]  
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \caption{model C}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Grid test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### First version

(labels protrude to the left margin):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[30pt]{\raisebox{40pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$R=1$}}}}%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[30pt]{\raisebox{40pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$R=2$}}}}%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[30pt]{\raisebox{40pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$R=3$}}}}%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \caption{model A}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]  
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \caption{model B}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]  
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \caption{model C}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Grid test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Adjust the lengths in the `\raisebox`es and the inner `\makebox`es according to your needs.

Comment: Very nice solution. What I don't like in your updated version, however, is that the first caption is not centered below the first column of pictures anymore. I used a separate column without a caption which holds the row labels to mitigate this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code: First, since you use `width=\textwidth`, the label and the image do not fit in one line and hence a new line is started for the image. The second problem is that the baseline of the image is not in its vertical center. This can be shifted by `\raisebox`. Assuming that all your images have the same width and height, the following might help':

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand\myrowlabel[1]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.30\textwidth}\raggedleft
    \myrowlabel{$R=1$}
    \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {test.png}}\\
    \myrowlabel{$R=2$}
    \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {test.png}}\\
    \myrowlabel{$R=3$}
    \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {test.png}}
    \caption{model A}
\end{subfigure}%
\hspace{1em}
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.30\textwidth}\raggedleft
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]  
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \caption{model B}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.30\textwidth}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]  
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {test.png}
    \caption{model C}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Grid test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that if `\textwidth` is small, `width=.9\textwidth` might not leave enough space for the label, too. Furthermore, you might consider using `\hspace{\fill}` instead of `\hspace{1em}` if you have a small `\textwidth`.
[image]